# How to manage 'submit' event at the same time using Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Forms as Test, this execute a script when event submit has ocurred. The script get the last email address from user and send an email with a messagge (test costumized score).

```
function manager(e) {
   var ultimoCorreo = getUltimoCorreo();
   validarPuntaje(e.response, ultimoCorreo);
}

function getUltimoCorreo() {
   var rango = HOJA_CALCULO.getRange(1,2,HOJA_CALCULO.getLastRow(),1); // Rango donde se encuentran los correos en la hoja de calculo
   var ultimoCorreo = rango.getCell(HOJA_CALCULO.getLastRow(),1).getValue();
   return ultimoCorreo.toLowerCase(); // Convertimos el correo a minusculas por si el usuario mandó mal el correo
```

}

This working OK. But I'm having troubles when several users send their answers at the same time. For example: When 4 users send the form at the same time, the emails with score of each is sent to last email.

How I can manage *'submit'* event at the same time in google forms?

**UPDATE:** I have been seen the [LockService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service) but I don't understand how working, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Lock Service and see what happens:

```
function manager(e) {
  var hasLock,lockService,ultimoCorreo;

  lockService = LockService.getScriptLock();

  hasLock = lockService.tryLock(10000);

  if (!hasLock) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, 'Failed to process your Form submission', 'The code failed');
    Logger.log('Could not obtain lock after 10 seconds.');
    return;
  }

  ultimoCorreo = getUltimoCorreo();
  validarPuntaje(e.response, ultimoCorreo);

  lockService.releaseLock();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sandy , thank you. I tried with LockServices class without success. But this response was useful for me!. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37405355/google-form-on-submit-send-email-lock-doesnt-work

Comment: Sorry to hear that it didn't work.  Maybe the problem is in a different part of the script?

Comment: Yep, my logic was bad from start. I was using the last row from spread sheet always. The solution was get all spread sheet with `sheet.getDataRange().getValues()` ... In the link there are more details. Anyway, thank you! :)